# functors on Zero-Object in $_RMod$-category

Tags: category-theory

If I have a functor $F:_RMod\rightarrow _SMod$ that is between the category of $R$-modules to the category of $S$-modules. Can I show that it must be the case that $F(0)=0$.

I know that $_RMod$ and $_SMod$ are both preaddative categories. So can I use this to show that every functor must have this property?

If we have that the map $Id_0:0\rightarrow 0$ is the identity map on $0$ then we know that $F(Id_0)=Id_{F(0)}$ but this doesn't seem like enough.

Thanks for any help

Comment: No. For instance, take a functor that maps every object to $S$ and every morphism to $0$...

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok, thanks. Is there some sort of restriction I can put on the functor $F$ so that this is true. If I could say that $F$ maps the zero morphism to the zero morphism then I could show that $Id_{F(0)}=0_{F(0)}$ and I would be done right?

Comment: Well yes, if you require that $F(0) = 0$ then $F(0) = 0$.

Comment: Well, $F$ would preserve zero objects, but only up to isomorphism.

Comment: If $F$ is an *additive* functor, then the claim is true.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Sorry my notation was that $0$ was the zero morphism not the zero object